# Customizing boot screen in android

Tags: android, android-ndk

i want customize the android boot screen, actually we are launching a new android powered tablet soon, for that i want to customize Boot Screen and i am using android ICS, please suggest me to achieve this.

Thanking you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use :

**adobe after effects software**

to customize the boot screen as you wish .

Hope this help